# AOSP build on OS X 10.7.5 fails: 'dprintf' not declared

Tags: osx-lion, android-source

I am trying to build AOSP on on OS X 10.7.5, with Xcode 4.2.1 and I get the error:

> host C++: libutils <= system/core/libutils/Printer.cpp
>
> system/core/libutils/Printer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void android::FdPrinter::printLine(const char*)’:
>
> system/core/libutils/Printer.cpp:123: **error: ‘dprintf’ was not declared in this scope**
>
> make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/Printer.o] Error 1

However if I myself write a program using the function dprintf it compiles fine, so I guess
 my problem is that AOSP compilation uses the wrong compiler / toolchain.
I tried to see what C compiler I have on my machine and I get this:

> $ whereis gcc
>
> /usr/bin/gcc
>
> $ ls -al /usr/bin/gcc
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Dec 16 23:08 /usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2

I read that llvm is not suported for aosp. Could this be the reason? If this is the case, how can I install another compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue upgrading to OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and XCode.

Comment: Try to update Xcode first, if don't want to upgrade to Mavericks.